# Get Latest row values from MySQL Database in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project. I am stuck in a situation, Where I want to retrieve latest row values of different attributes from MySQL database in django, but my query always return first row values. I am using orm query. I want latest row values entered by user through input form. Here is my code:

views.py:

```
def success(request):
  ip_value = NewDevice.objects.values('ip').latest('created_at')
  start_time_value = NewDevice.objects.values('start_time').latest('created_at')
  end_time_value = NewDevice.objects.values('end_time').latest('created_at')
  return response
```

models.py:

```
class NewDevice(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
  ip = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  start_time = models.TimeField()
  end_time = models.TimeField()
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  class Meta:
    db_table = "live"
```

Database Results:

```
with live (id,ip,start_time,end_time,created_at) as (values
  (1 ,'1.1.1.1','10:57:00','18:23:00','13:22:29'),
  (2, '0.0.0.0','11:57:00','11:58:00','05:57:30'),
  (3 ,'10.10.10.10','13:49:00','13:50:00','08:49:20')
)
```

Whenever my function def success executes, the query inside this function always print row 1 value which is:

```
(1 ,'1.1.1.1','10:57:00','18:23:00','13:22:29')
```

But I want always latest row values when record will insert into database. Kindly help to get rid of this issue.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#latest , chek it helps you
NewDevice.objects.latest()

Comment: @Jisson, I think you didn't notice, I have three columns ip, start_data and end_date and I want their latest values in three each different variables and therefore, I want to add three queries each for them